# Are questions about the Minecraft forums considered relevant to the "minecraft" tag?

Tags: support, minecraft

Are questions about the Minecraft Forums (http://minecraftforum.net) considered relevant on  gaming.stackexchange.com, or its meta site? The Minecraft forums are a huge part of the Minecraft community, so I think questions relating to the forums might be useful here (for people who aren't familiar with the Minecraft forums.)

Any discussion about the Minecraft community is likely to involve some discussion of the Minecraft forums - would discussions about the community of Minecraft be considered off-topic?

Answer (score 5):

There's already the ideal place to ask about the Minecraft forums: the Minecraft forums themselves.

While I think that tools and services specifically targeted at gamers are on-topic, I don't think it makes sense to ask questions about another forum here. The best place to ask those questions is the forum itself.

Comment: On the Minecraft Forums, there's no reputation system for questions and answers, so finding useful questions and answers on the Minecraft forums isn't always easy. I'd prefer to ask questions about the Minecraft on the Stack Exchange network, so that I'll be able to find relevant answers (and receive notifications whenever I get a reply to a topic.)

Comment: Could you add some example questions? I'm having a hard time imagining questions about the Minecraft forum itself that would be a good fit for SE

Comment: Still, I'd be more likely to get relevant answers by posting questions on the Minecraft Forums (than by posting them elsewhere.)

Comment: I think you're mostly correct - there wouldn't be much point in asking questions about the Minecraft Forums on the Stack Exchange network, unless the question was something like this: *"Is it possible to transfer questions from the Minecraft Forums to the Stack Exchange Network?"*